# "Operation not supported in transactions" While Copy/Paste Records in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When copy / pasting cells from Excel into an Access Subform, when no parent record has been created, will result in an error - as expected.

The problem, is that after this error occurs access gets locked in a state where all subsequent data that is entered results in an ***Operation not supported in transactions*** error.  When you open the table, you can see that the newly added data is not yet in the table - so it appears as if Access is in fact engaged in some sort of transaction.

I have tried hitting 'Save' .. 'Refresh' .. and even adding an AfterInsert event to force a commitTrans() but have had no luck - and Access claims there is no transaction underway

There is no error if the records are entered manually. The problem only seems to occur when pasting records.  I'm guessing that Access is creating a transaction to handle the multiple record operations and is not properly recovering from the error.

I can remove the 'Required' flag and it will work - but then you have orphan records.   I was thinking that perhaps an After Insert Data Macro could be used to add a new Batch with a default batch Name, and auto-fill the new BatchID into the Items table.  I am not certain how that would be done however.

I did try to remove the 'Required' flag and trap for the error using a Before Change Data Macro - but while it cut down on the errors - it still produced the same *Operation not supported in transactions* error.

I have looked up the error on the Microsoft Knowledgebase, but did not find anything specific to my circumstances.  I searched stackoverflow for the error message and found nothing.

I created a new database and was able to replicate the issue.

**Steps to Replicate**

*Set up the Database*

1. Create a new ACCDB database in Access 2010
2. Create a Table called 'Batches', with the following fields:

   - BatchID (AutoNumber) (Primary Key)
   - BatchName (Text)
3. Create a Table called 'Items', with the following fields:

   - RecordID (AutoNumber) (Primary Key)
   - BatchID (Long Integer)

     - Set *Required* attribute to True
   - Data - Text
4. Create a Relationship, linking Batches.BatchID to Items.BatchID

   - Include all Records from Batches, and matching records from Items
   - Enforce Referential Integrity
   - Cascade Updates / Deletes
5. Create a Form called 'Form'

   - Set the Recordsource to Batches
   - Add in the BatchID and Batch name Textboxes
   - Add in a SubForm/SubReport Control

     - Set Source Object to "Table.Items"
     - Set Link Master Fields to "BatchID"
     - Set Link Child Fields to "BatchID"
     - Set "Filter On Empty Master" = Yes
6. Create sample data (Using the Form)

   - Create a New Record in Batches.

     - Set BatchName = "Test"
   - Create a New Record in Items.

     - Reference the Batch Record.
     - Set Data = "Test"

As you can see, by hand this works fine.

*Copy and Paste Data From Excel*

1. In Excel

   - From A1-A10 enter one letter per cell running down: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
   - Highlight the cells A1-A10
   - Copy (Control+C)
2. In Access, using the Form:

   - Add a New Batch Record.  It should say "(New)" in BatchID TextBox
   - Do NOT enter a Batch Name
   - In the Sub-Form, click the record selector (*) for the new record to select the entire row.  Type Control+V to paste.
   - Click OK for *"You must enter a value in the 'Data.BatchID' field.* error

     - This error may repeat.  Keep Clicking OK
     - If it asks "Do you want to suppress further error messages..." answer Yes
   - Click OK for the *"Records that Microsoft Access was unable to paste have been inserted into a new table called 'Paste Errors.'* notification
   - Fill in the Batch Name Textbox with "TestName"
   - Try to gracefully recover.  Hit Escape.  Change the Record.

At this point - you should see the BatchID entered, the Batch Name, and the New Data.  Everything *appears* to be working as expected.  If you try to refresh or navigate to another batch record - you will get the error ***Operation not supported in transactions***.   Access will continue to display this error message until we close and reopen the form. The data you pasted will not have made it into the database.

Normally someone with a bit of tech savvy will realize something isn't going well and close out of the database and re-open ... but unfortunately I have users that play "whack-a-mole" with any popup boxes and then try to continue on - so I'd like to make things as bulletproof as possible.

**Desired Solution**

I'd like a workaround to the problem, that won't eventually lead to other quirks with access, duplicate values, etc.

In my own experience, using VBA to 'fix-up' keys isn't reliable.  Data macros seem to be a lot more reliable - but they can be tricky to set up - they aren't very mainstream yet (I'd say there should be a *ms-access-data-macros* tag on stackoverflow but there isn't yet)

Comment: Could you attach or link sample files of ACCDB and xls

Comment: Which part of the recreation instructions did you run into difficulty with?  I would like to clarify the question so it can be followed.

As for attachments - Stackoverflow doesn't support file attachments.  When linking to another site (ie. file hosting) the original question tends to out-live the attachments - and so people finding the question are not able to access the attachments.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your results, even with your copy of the `.accdb` file. When I paste I get the "You must enter a value in the 'Items.BatchID' field." message. After I dismiss it the subform is still dirty but anything I do after that simply re-displays that message until I hit [Esc] to undo the subform changes. Then things are back to normal. I tried it on both 32-bit and 64-bit Access 2010 just to see if it made any difference (it didn't).

Comment: I couldn't recreate too. But i know for sure there is such error in some circumstances as i had it with acces 2000. but i don`t remember how we had risen it and how we solved it.

Comment: Why don't you want to create New Record in Batches when sub form gotfocus without having Master record?

Comment: @DHW Since the others can't reproduce the problem, please indicate your Office 2010 service pack level.

Comment: Version: 14.0.7015.1000 (32-bit)

So it is looking like an Access Bug?  I got the same results on my Access at home and work - had assumed Office updated automatically.

Just to confirm - you guys are copying and *PASTING* into Access?   It always works if you type - but the issue seems to only be with pasting records.

Comment: May be the way you paste is different? Do you select column or row before paste? (but i've tested both)

Comment: The Access 2010 version that I used for testing was 14.0.7106.5003 (both 32-bit and 64-bit). That's what regular old Microsoft Update had patched me up to.

Comment: Okay, I've been able to recreate it now. Suggested refinement to instructions: "In the subform, click the record selector (`*`) for the new record to select the entire row, then type [Ctrl-V] to paste." (Previously I had just clicked in the `Data` field on the new record and then pasted because that's the field into which I was going to be pasting the data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested workaround:

In the [Batches] table, set the `Required` property of the [BatchName] field to `Yes`.

Change the `Tab Stop` property of the [BatchID] text box to "No". That will give the [BatchName] text box the default focus when the form opens.

Have the `On Current` event of the form give the [BatchName] text box the focus for new records (`IsNull(Me.BatchID) = True`).

Make the form dirty when the [BatchName] text box loses focus.

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim DeletePending As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DeletePending = False
    Me.ItemSubForm.Enabled = False  ' Disable Subform by default
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    If IsNull(Me.BatchID) Then
        Me.BatchName.SetFocus
        ' Disable Subform if BatchID is NULL
        Me.ItemSubForm.Enabled = False
    Else
        ' Enable SubForm Otherwise
        Me.ItemSubForm.Enabled = False 
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeDelConfirm(Cancel As Integer, Response As Integer)
    DeletePending = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    DeletePending = False
End Sub

Private Sub BatchName_LostFocus()
    If IsNull(Me.BatchID) And Not DeletePending Then
        Me.Dirty = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When the user clicks on the subform (and off the [BatchName] text box) they make the form dirty and BatchID gets a value. Then they can paste and they don't get the "You must enter a value..." message for [BatchID]. If they haven't entered a [BatchName] value they now get prompted for *it* (because it is now `Required`), but at least they can gracefully recover from that.

Updated 2013-11-09 18:40 UTC:

In playing around with this a bit more I discovered two quirks:

1. If you deleted the last parent record Access would do it and then immediately create another new one in its place.
2. If you navigated into the "new" parent record and then immediately backed out (e.g., via the <kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> keys) Access would create a new record and then leave you on that record with the form dirty. Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then moving off the "new" record worked, and it didn't cause any errors, but it certainly could be confusing to the user.

I have updated the answer to try and address these issues. I added a bit more VBA code to track "DeletePending" status. I also added the requirement that [BatchName] be set to `Required = Yes` in the [Batches] table. The latter makes it slightly more intuitive (albeit slightly more annoying) if the user move into the "new" record and then immediately moves back out again.

Comment: What you have is good for stopping the user from pasting right off - but if they hit escape they can still paste and cause the error.   However if you disable the subform - your solution appears to be bulletproof.     I will suggest an edit for your question to add in the checks.

Comment: The idea I was toying with was to use an *After Insert* data macro on the Items table.  If the BatchID is null, it checks two local vars.  The first is a timestamp - if its within a second or two of the current time, it would set the BatchID to the value in a second local var.   If there was no timestamp, or it is too old, it would create a new record in Batches, get the new BatchID - then set a timestamp and the batchID. What I liked about this solution is that it would work without form and in untrusted mode. What I didn't like is that I couldn't figure out how to bring this into fruition :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long until I finally understood what is happening to cause this error.  It would take an article of considerable length to go into the details rather than a blog response to explain it all.  If anyone is interested they can leave a contact method and I will contact them and explain it in detail.
However, for those who want to figure this out, I can save you a lot of time by giving you the idea behind the issue:
When you are performing a data transaction in a bound sub-form, you cannot reference other objects.  The internal code of the transaction process does not allow this.  For example, if you have code in the Form_BeforeUpdate event that attempts to open another form while in the midst of a sub-form data transaction, you will get error 3246. You can have code that creates variables, set values, references the sub-form controls, etc. but you cannot go out to another object.
This makes sense if you think about it.  Who knows what the user or code might do once it gets itself into another form or object.  It may never come back or get involved in other errors that leave the transaction hanging.  That's why the transaction must complete first.
This means that you must trap and dismiss error 2115 that is caused when a user tries to click on an area outside the sub-form while in the midst of a transaction.  This usually occurs during large copy and paste where the user becomes inpatient or starts to proceed to another record while still in the midst of the sub-form transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old storry, I was also strugling with this.
My solution was to re-desing the process so the user closes the form receiving the data in order to save the records inserted. Is nor elegant but efficient and saved me from guessing each and every event which could occure.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the undesired internal transaction is enough to
code the sub-form Error event with:

```vbs
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Response = acDataErrContinue

End Sub
```

A general approach for intercepting sub-forms events is

```vbs
' parent form code
' ---------------------------------------------------
Private WithEvents subFormObj As [Form_Sottomaschera items]

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Set subFormObj = Me.Sottomaschera_items.Form

End Subcode here

' asynchronous way
Private Sub subFormObj_isInserting()

    Me.batchName = vbNullString         ' this resolves the new ID issue

End Sub

' synchronous way
Public Sub subFormInserting()

    Me.batchName = vbNullString

End Sub

' sub-form code
' ---------------------------------------------------
Public Event isInserting()              ' for asynchronous way

Dim parentFormObj As Form_Maschera1     ' for synchronous way

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

    parentFormObj.subFormInserting
    RaiseEvent isInserting
'    Cancel = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Response = acDataErrContinue

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Set parentFormObj = Me.Parent

End Sub
```

where `[Maschera1]` is the main form and `[Sottomaschera items]` the sub-form.

Unfortunately it doesn't resolve the paste issue.

To definitely resolve issue you need to save parent record + a `SetFocus` trick, either synchronous or asynchronous:

```vbs
Private Sub subFormObj_isInserting()

    Me.batchName = vbNullString
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
'    DoEvents
    Me.batchName.SetFocus

End Sub

Public Sub subFormInserting()

    Me.batchName = vbNullString
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
'   DoEvents
    Me.batchName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this already - as you pointed out - it doesn't stop the paste error - and the form error event doesn't seem to trap for it.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in my case as the whole point is to paste the records from Excel into an Access datasheet.

Comment: I apologize for wanting to insist... it's a bounty issue :). 
I omitted the Datasheet point of request and the way you need to paste your data. But if you choose to use a sub-form and getting the desired view at run-time, you'll get the required paste action simply selecting the header of the target table column. 
You'll get the possibilities of an Access Datasheet and the control over a Subform just setting acCurViewDatasheet view mode in the main form open event. Furthemore you have to set TextBox.EnterKeyBehavior to False for the textbox targeting the paste data and viewed in datasheet mode

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly do you want to achive, so this answer may be inadequate.
You can

- set your subform property `.Visible = False` when `Me.NewRecord = True` to prevent entering data into it
- force saving record of the main form to the table after adding Batch name by setting `.Dirty = False` in After Update event triggered by pressing Enter. It allows also to avoid not saving records of a subsform to a table after adding few records to a main form in some databases, at least with dynamical subform .Recordsource.
- set your subform property `.Visible = True`

The code below works for Form View and perhaps should be extended (develop) somehow for other Views.

Set .Tag of the subform Child and all other controls you want to hide / show to "a".

```vbs
Private Sub Form_Current()

If Me.CurrentView = 1 Then

    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
       ShowControls False
    ElseIf Me![Items subform Child].Visible = False Then
       ShowControls True
    End If

End If

End Sub

Private Sub BatchName_Text_AfterUpdate()

Dim NewRecordx As Boolean

If Me![Items subform Child].Visible = False And Me.CurrentView = 1 Then ShowControls True

NewRecordx = Me.NewRecord

If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False 'save the new record to the table

If Me.CurrentView = 1 And NewRecordx Then Me![Items subform Child].Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub ShowControls(bVisible As Boolean)

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
   If ctl.Tag = "a" Then ctl.Visible = bVisible
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I reported this as a bug through Microsoft Premier Support a number of years ago with a concise standalone repro case.  It appears this was finally resolved in October 2021 with KB5001978.